# JavaScript and ASP.NET - Cookies with Key / Value Pairs

Tags: asp.net, javascript

This question mixes client-side scripting with server-side parsing.

In some cases, I'm writing a cookie to the user's browser using the `document.cookie` property. In other cases, I'm writing the same cookie to the user's browser through the ASP.NET `Response` object.

When I'm writing the `HttpCookie` on the server-side, I am using the Values collection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httpcookie.values%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to store key/value pairs in the cookie. I would also like to be able to write key-value pairs to the cookie through JavaScript.

How do I create cookies with Key/Value pairs via JavaScript that ASP.NET can parse?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to get the value of the main cookie via javascript.

For example if your main cookie name is UserDetails and the sub elements are FirstName and LastName asp.net should set the UserDetails Cookie value as follows.

FirstName=Jon&LastName=Doe

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is a Request.Cookies that you can use to read cookie values with.

HTH.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking if he can mimic the NameValuePair collection notation in the cookie on the client side (i.e. add items to the cookie using a name-value-pair which c# will understand in the code-behind)..

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote [a blog post about this exact topic](http://cdmckay.org/blog/2012/02/12/creating-asp-net-httpcookie-compatible-multi-valued-cookies-in-javascript/). Here's the JavaScript to create an ASP.NET HttpCookie-compatible multi-valued cookie:

```
var setMultiValuedCookie = function(name, values) {
    var valuePairs = [];
    for (var n in values) {
        valuePairs.push(n + "=" + values[n]);
    }
    var cookieValue = valuePairs.join("&");
    document.cookie = name + "=" + cookieValue;
};

// Usage:
setMultiValuedCookie("TestCookie", { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" });
```